# Facing "system#unknownerror" when trying to get the ASSET details in maximo from java code

Tags: java, maximo

Here I am trying to get ASSET details in simple java

Here is the code

```
MXSession session = MXSession.getSession();
session.setHost("localhost:13400/MXServer");
session.setUserName(user);
session.setPassword(pwd);
session.connect();
```

The connection was successful.
Then I tried to get the asset details with the code

```
MboSetRemote assetMboSet = session.getMboSet("ASSET");
assetMboSet.setOrderBy("ASSETNUM");
MboRemote assetMbo;
for(int j=0; ((assetMbo = assetMboSet.getMbo(j)) != null); j++)
{
String assetNum = assetMbo.getString("ASSETNUM");
String location = assetMbo.getString("LOCATION");
String desc = assetMbo.getString("DESCRIPTION");
System.out.println(assetNum + " - " + location + " - " + desc);
}
```

it is giving me the error and could not proceed further in the line

```
MboSetRemote assetMboSet = session.getMboSet("ASSET");
```

saying

```
Exception in thread "main" psdi.util.MXSystemException: system#unknownerror
at psdi.util.RMISession.getMboSet(RMISession.java:330)
```

Please suggest me how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

My friend I just tried your code scripth and it works fine, here is a [snapshot of my environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMpsk.png) which shows your work.

This problem may occur, If the admin mode is on OR you need to change take a look at sessions, to do that.

> you can go to the users application.
>   Select action > manage sessions.

- You can view users who are currently logged into the system.
- You can log out a user from the system or log out and block a user from the system.
- You can see the login history of users.